# rails: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<h3>Create Your Pokemon!</h3>
<%= simple_form_for @pokemon do |p|, :url => pokemon_path(id: @pokemon) %>
  <%= p.input :name, placeholder:'Pikacharmander' %>
  <%= p.button :submit,'Create' %>
<% end %>
```

My code is like above, but every time I run it I got this error

```
syntax error, unexpected ','
...imple_form_for @pokemon do |p|, :url => pokemon_path(id: @po...
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: try this <%= simple_form_for @pokemon, :url => pokemon_path(id: @pokemon) do |p| %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below fix:-

```
<h3>Create Your Pokemon!</h3>
<%= simple_form_for @pokemon, :url => pokemon_path(id: @pokemon) do |p| %>
  <%= p.input :name, placeholder:'Pikacharmander' %>
  <%= p.button :submit,'Create' %>
<% end %>
```